# Proper way to URL redirect from old product to new url considering SEO

Tags: magento-1.7, url-rewrite, seo

I have product that have been disabled with url xyz.html.
I have new product with url abc.html
Now  i want to redirect user from xyz.html to abc.html, so am trying to created url rewrite as follows

Request Path :xyz.html
Target Path  : abc.html
Redirect : Permanant 301

It throws me errors saying Request Path already exist.Its valid as the xyz.html is already created for old product.

What would be the best way to deal with such cases also considering SEO in mind

Answer (score 1):

you can just delete the url rewrite for `xyz.html` or edit it and make the target path for it `abc.html`

Comment: thats the only way i found this to work...unfortunately if you are editing 20 products it will take you a day to fix all the URL redirects...this sucks